# JPA Custom Query throwing error insert enum body to complete EnumDeclaration

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to create a custom query using springboot, JPA @Query annotation. But I'm getting "insert enum to complete EnumDecalation" error and "insert enum identifier to complete EnumHeaderName". Why is this?  Here is my code:

```
public interface ScripturesRepository extends JpaRepository<Scriptures, Long>{
    
    @Query(value = "SELECT s FROM SCRIPTURES s WHERE CATEGORY =?1 AND READ=false LIMIT 5", nativeQuery = true);
    public List<Scriptures> findByCategory(String category);

}
```

But I get the following compilation error:

[image: compilation error message]

Comment: Remove semicolon after `@Query()` here  `...nativeQuery = true)*;*`

Comment: Thank you! That solved it!